# Form validation using Jquery

Tags: jquery

When I submit my form I need to validate a txt field for not null and other stuff through jquery. But for only one submit button among all the other buttons it must validate that .I am doing the following

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    /* validate form */
    $("#getEstimateId").click(function(e) {
        alert('get Estimate');
    });
    $("#get").click(function(e) {
        alert('get');
    });
    $("#getEstimateId").click(function() {
        alert('getting in ');
        var validator = $("#editDMBasketContentsId").validate({
            rules: {
                "postal": {
                    required:true,
                    number: true,
                    exactlength : 4,
                    digits : true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                "postal": {
                    required: "This field is required",
                    number :"Invalid entry please enter numbers only.",
                    exactlength : "Exactly 4 characters must be entered",
                    digits : "Please enter digits only"
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.is(":radio"))
                    error.appendTo(element.parent().next().next());
                else if (element.is(":checkbox"))
                    error.appendTo(element.next().next());
                else
                    error.appendTo(element.parent().find(".status"));
            },
            submitHandler: function () {
                document.forms['deliveryEstimate'].submit();
            },
            success: function (label) {
                label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("checked");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It is going inside the method when i click the button and displays all the alerts but then the validation is not happening. Any suggestions on why it is happening so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first few lines were preventing it from the validation now sorted it out

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    /* validate form */
    $("#getEstimateId").click(function() {
        alert('getting in ');
        var validator = $("#editDMBasketContentsId").validate({
            rules: {
                "postal": {
                    required:true,
                    number: true,
                    exactlength : 4,
                    digits : true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                "postal": {
                    required: "This field is required",
                    number :"Invalid entry please enter numbers only.",
                    exactlength : "Exactly 4 characters must be entered",
                    digits : "Please enter digits only"
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.is(":radio"))
                    error.appendTo(element.parent().next().next());
                else if (element.is(":checkbox"))
                    error.appendTo(element.next().next());
                else
                    error.appendTo(element.parent().find(".status"));
            },
            submitHandler: function () {
                document.forms['deliveryEstimate'].submit();
            },
            success: function (label) {
                label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("checked");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: edit your response and use the {} button to format the code parts